# Using String.format() to create a sqlite table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, string-formatting, sqliteopenhelper

Stack Overflow,

I am trying to understand how to use String.format() to create a sqlite database for my Android app.

I have a public class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper and a private inner class that contains private static final strings which I intend to be the column names for my database.

**Music Database Class Code**

```
public class SaturnMusicDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private Context mContext;

   // Necessary public constructor to use SQLiteOpenHelper 
    public SaturnMusicDatabase(Context context){
        super(context, "SaturnMusic.db"), null,1);
        mContext = context;
    }
    // The columns beginning with an underscore are the primary key
private static final class Songs{
     private static final String TABLE = "songs";
     private static final String COL_ARTIST ="_artist";
     private static final String COL_ALBUM="_album";
     private static final String COL_TITLE ="_title";
     private static final String COL_GENRE = "genre";
     private static final String COL_LENGTH ="length";
     private static final String COL_Number ="number";
 }
@Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     String queryMakeSong = String.format
             ("create table %s (primary key(%s, %s, %s)%s, %s, %s)",
                     Songs.TABLE, Songs.COL_ARTIST, Songs.COL_ALBUM, Songs.COL_TITLE,
                    Songs.COL_GENRE, Songs.COL_LENGTH, Songs.COL_Number);
     db.execSQL(queryMakeSong);
 }

 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
 }
}
```

My confusion is with the create statement. The way I understand how String.format() works is that the % sign followed by a modifier determines the data type to use when formatting the data that is passed into the function.

My intention is to create a table named songs that has six fields, three of which are primary keys: Artist, Album, and Title.

It makes sense that the field names should be strings, so that is why I chose to use the 's' modifier. Does this mean that the data that will be stored in these fields will be strings? Or does it mean that the field names are strings and I have to specify what data type these fields should hold in the create table statement?

If the former, that is not what I want for all of my fields. Things like LENGTH and NUMBER should be storing integers. Which makes me think that they should use the 'd' modifier.

Please share if any of my syntax is wrong, and how I can correct it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shouldn't.  Use bind variables instead.  Using String.format leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection security bugs, bind variables avoid that.  If you aren't doing a dynamic query (like for a create table) then just put in the raw SQL rather than doing a format, it will be more readable down the line when maintaining the query.

But to answer your question-  the symbols in format have nothing to do with the data types stored in it in the db, because String.format doesn't know anything about the database, or that its being used for a database query.  It just outputs formatted strings.  If the actual value you're putting into that string is a number, use %d.  If its a string like a table name, column name, etc, use %s.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer.

If you have the time can you show an example of how bind variables would work in the context of this problem?

Comment: Bind variables do not work for column names, and SQL injection is not possible when the inserted strings are constants.

Comment: @CL Reread my comment.I said for non dynamic queries just use the sql as a raw statement. But even when using constants you should use bind variables where possible, they optimize better, and prevent the possibility of later reactor into dynamic data by less experienced programmers

Answer (score 1):

> The way I understand how String.format() works is that the % sign
>   followed by a modifier determines the data type to use when formatting
>   the data that is passed into the function.

I believe that the **`%`** is followed by the argument's index i.e %1... substitutes the first argument %2... the 2nd etc.

It is the **`$`** that precedes the type/conversion.

So (at a guess) you would have been attempting :-

```
    ..... create table %1$s (primary key(%2$s, %3$s, %4$s)%5$s, %6$s, %7$s)"
```

---

> Does this mean that the data that will be stored in these fields will
>   be strings?

Not at all. In fact SQLite is quite flexible in that you can store any type of value in any column (***an exception being the rowid column which will always be of TYPE INTEGER***, which is by default generally transparent; defining a column as `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`) creates an alias for the rowid column named ?? (where ?? would be a valid column name e.g. **_id**).

In you case as you have not specified a column type, the column types will all be BLOB, as per the rule (#3) -

> If the declared type for a column contains the string "BLOB" or **if no
>   type** is specified then the column has affinity BLOB.

However, when actually storing a value the Storage Class comes into play and the following rule is applied :-

> A column with affinity BLOB does not prefer one storage class over
>   another and no attempt is made to coerce data from one storage class
>   into another.

i.e. the data will be stored according to the type of the data being applied.

You may wish to look at [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)  from which the above has been based.

As an example this Table  :-

[image]

Could have data as per (The Legend describes the colour coding) :-

[image]

***This shows that every row/column combination actually has it's own TYPE.***

---

> Or does it mean that the field names are strings and I have to specify
>   what data type these fields should hold in the create table statement?

As from the above you don't although you may prefer to.

> I have a private inner class that contains private static final
>   strings

You may find it more useful to have names as `public static final String`. You then have a single definition of the name which can be used throughout.

i.e. you might want to access the data at some time, in which case you may want a column name, say to get data from that column from the table.

Compare the following:-

```
Cursor csr = db.query("snogs",null,null,null,null,null.null); // What idiot used snogs instead of songs?????

Cursor csr = db.query(Songs.TABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
```

The former = table not found error because I inadvertently smelt(**here I go again :)**) songs incorrectly (obviously on purpose).

The latter would be hard to get wrong with many IDE's as `Snogs.TABLE` would be shown as incorrect in the editor and wouldn't compile.

Using Column names (especially from a single source) instead of hard-coding offsets when retrieving data is less likely to result in issues. So instead of

```
    String artist = csr.getString(5); // what column is this????
```

the more long-winded :-

```
     String artist = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(Songs.COL_Number));
```

is less likely to result in issues e.g. :-

Say you modifed the table to include another column and that column was place before the last column, then the former would then get the wrong data until change to 6, whilst the latter wouldn't need changing.